# how to get intersection between 2 lists faster

Tags: go

I have 2 lists, one list element type is structA, the other list element type is structB, there's common field `string name` between structA and structB. how to get intersection element which has same `name` between 2 lists and avoid o(n^2) time complexity using golang.

```
type structA struct {
   name string
   ....
}
type structB struct {
   name string
   ..
}
```

noted: `name` field in each list is not unique, so convert map way is not a solution

Comment: Convert one list to a map (example map[string][]structA where keys are name and value is a slice of elements with that name). Iterate through the second list looking for matches in the map.

Comment: Keep them both sorted and walk through each at the same time. But without details of your structures and data distributions, we can only guess.

Comment: Faster than what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having lists that are not unique does not prevent you from using a map; you can do something like the following ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/greW-QGfVi1)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type structA struct {
        name       string
        otherfield int
    }
    type structB struct {
        name           string
        differentField bool
    }

    aSlice := []structA{
        {name: "foo", otherfield: 1},
        {name: "foo", otherfield: 2},
        {name: "unique", otherfield: 3},
        {name: "one", otherfield: 4},
    }
    bSlice := []structB{
        {name: "foo", differentField: true},
        {name: "foo", differentField: false},
        {name: "noIntersection", differentField: true},
        {name: "one", differentField: false},
    }

    inA := make(map[string][]interface{})
    for _, a := range aSlice {
        inA[a.name] = append(inA[a.name], a)
    }

    intersect := make(map[string][]interface{})
    for _, b := range bSlice {
        if _, ok := intersect[b.name]; ok {
            intersect[b.name] = append(intersect[b.name], b)
            continue
        }
        if a, ok := inA[b.name]; ok {
            intersect[b.name] = append(a, b)
            continue
        }

    }
    fmt.Println(intersect)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use Maps in Golang. The average complexity time is O(n) because a Map in golang base on a Hash table.
Example Code:

```
aMap := make(map[string][]*structA)
for _,a := range aList {
    aMap[a.name] = append(aMap[a.name], a)
}
bMap := make(map[string][]*structB)
for _,b := range bList {
    bMap[b.name] = append(bMap[b.name], b)
}
//get an intersection of aList and bList
itersections := make([]*structB, 0, len(aList))
for k,v := range aMap {
    if b, ok := bMap[k];ok {
        itersections = append(intersections, b...)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think you missed the part about repeated names in your solution.

Comment: oh yeah. you are right. Thanks @NuLo